# How to copy zipfiles automatically from local file system to HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

As I know `copyFromLocal <localSrc> <dest>` this command works copy files to HDFS. I don't want to copy manually because I am getting files from sources on weekly basis it's difficult to copy manually every time.

**below is my requirement.**

when I drop `file.zip` to local file system path: `/usr/data/ingestion/` file should automatically absorb from local and copy to HDFS path like  `hdfs://usr/data/raw/file.zip`

Is it possible? or any frameworks supports such feature?

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way would be to use `cron`.

Comment: @Hareesh - see updated answer .... script should look for `*.ready` files and it will copy those `*.zip` files to hdfs in every 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can write shell script like this...and schedule to run daily from cron or manually:

```
#!/bin/sh
local_zip_dir=/home/username/data
hdfs_zip_dir=/user/cloudera/data

for local_zip_file in $(ls -1 $local_zip_dir/*.zip)
do
   file_name=$(echo $local_zip_file|awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
   if hadoop fs -test –e  $hdfs_zip_dir/$file_name;
   then
               echo "$local_zip_file already copied to hdfs"
   else
               echo "Coping $local_zip_file to $hdfs_zip_dir"
               hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $local_zip_file $hdfs_zip_dir/$file_name
   fi
done
```

P.S: fix the syntax errors if any as this is not tested and answered from mobile app

---

Further in your step of droping zip file on local path, you can drop empty file:

for example your droping at local should do these two step:

```
original file to copy: file.zip
empty file copied as:  file.zip.ready
```

then shell script should be checking in every one or five minutes if there are any `*.ready` files, if so then just copy `file.zip` and remove `.ready` file after copying to `hdfs`:

something like this...

```
#!/bin/sh
local_zip_dir=/home/username/data
hdfs_zip_dir=/user/cloudera/data

while(true)
do  
 for local_zip_file in $(ls -1 $local_zip_dir/*.ready)
 do
   file_name=$(echo $local_zip_file|awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'|awk -F '.' '{print $1,$2}'|sed 's/ /./')
   if hadoop fs -test –e  $hdfs_zip_dir/$file_name;
   then
               echo "$local_zip_file already copied to hdfs"
   else
               echo "Coping $local_zip_file to $hdfs_zip_dir"
               hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $local_zip_file $hdfs_zip_dir/$file_name
               #lets delete .ready file
               rm -f $local_zip_file 
   fi
 done
#sleep for 5 minutes
sleep 300
done
```